# ¿Como enviar comandos AT en arduino?

Tags: arduino

Tengo un proyecto en arudino con un sensor PIR, lo que busco es que desde aquí, pueda enviar comandos AT al serial monitor cuando se cumpla la condición, ya que al final quiero juntarlo con un modulo wifi esp8266.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que quieres enviarle comandos AT al esp?

Comment: Copia y pega código, te ayudamos a darle formato, las imágenes se utilizan en otros aspectos, revisa este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hay montones de recursos que abordan el tema, tanto en castellano como inglés. Busca "Arduino ESP como conectar"